# Cucumber - Running feature files in Parallel - JUnit+Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, parallel-execution

I am unable to find solution to configure gradle to run cucumber features in parallel using JUnit.

Cucumber site is documented with Maven solution for parallel execution. It is not documented for gradle.

Please help me with gradle configuration which is equivalent to below configuration in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
         <threadCount>4</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You simply can't with Gradle and JUnit 4. Try JUnit 5 instead: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#parallel-execution

Comment: I am unable to filter feature files; Can you please help me; All feature files are under resource folder com.automation.runners and @cucumber class at the same package but under java folder. cucumber.features=com/automation/runners/Demo.feature -> This entry is not working in junit-platform.properties file